# задача на часы и минуты python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Катя узнала, что ей для сна надо XX минут. В отличие от Коли, Катя ложится спать после полуночи в HH часов и MM минут. Помогите Кате определить, на какое время ей поставить будильник, чтобы он прозвенел ровно через XX минут после того, как она ляжет спать.

На стандартный ввод, каждое в своей строке, подаются значения XX, HH и MM. Гарантируется, что Катя должна проснуться в тот же день, что и заснуть. Программа должна выводить время, на которое нужно поставить будильник: в первой строке часы, во второй — минуты.

Sample Input 1:

```
480
1
2
```

Sample Output 1:

```
9
2
```

Sample Input 2:

```
475
1
55
```

Sample Output 2:

```
9
50
```

```py
import math
x = int(input()) #min
h = int(input()) #hours
m = int(input()) #min
x_2 = x%60
x_1 = int(math.ceil(x/60))+h
print(x_1)
print(x_2)
```

Comment: `kolya=None` зачем он здесь?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, можно, конечно, и вот так:

```
x_1=h*60+m
x_2=x_1+x
print(x_2//60)
print(x_2%60)
```

Хотя так делать -  извращение. Для решения подобных задач  существует библиотека `datatime`. Вот только я не уверен, что вы ее уже учили.